# Replace double quote(") with escape double quote(\") is not working in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, ios11, xcode9

I am trying to replace double quote (") with escape double quote(\"), but it is unable to replace in iOS 11. Same works fine till iOS 10. I am using Xcode 9.1.

Example:

Input from search bar : "Course"

```
NSString *modifedSearchString = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\""\""];
```

Expected Output : \"Course\" (Working this till iOS 10)

O/p in iOS 11 : "Course"

Anyone facing same issue?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your code looks okay, i tried it on iPhone X having iOS 11 in XCode 9.1. output to console is correct as expected.

Comment: Consider that the backslashes are (virtual) escape characters and are often added automatically.

Comment: @Baig.. Issue is when i input string in double quotes from search bar.

Comment: When you println(searchBar.text) , what's output?

Comment: How do you check the output? Note that some debug info will add the backslashes to the output even though they’re not actually present in the string. If you want to include a backslash, you need to double it. So ˋ\"` should actually be written `\\\"`.

Comment: It's "Course". Same output before and after replacing double quotes.

Comment: @jcaron.. I am trying with same way only.

Comment: if it has double quotes then its strange, why its not working with you. because you told that it works if string is in variable as i tried it as well. and it was working too.

Comment: if ([searchBar.text containsString:@"\""]) {
        NSLog(@"Found double quote");
}

I tried to check if string contains double quotes in source string. It prints log in iOS 10 but not in iOS 11.

Comment: Stupid question... are you sure your quotes are regular straight quotes `"ˋ? Could they not be any of the “fancy” quotes `”` or `“`?

Comment: @jcaron.. Shouldn't do loose comment without full information.

Comment: Guys got the issue. It was due to introduction of smart punctuation in iOS 11. Quotes are no longer being encoded as ", but instead as a new character when entered from the new keyboard in iOS11. To avoid this, please turn off smart puncutation. Please see below links for more info: https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/778otd/ios_11_no_longer_encodes_double_quotes_as_the/

Comment: I feel like the second string would be more straightforwardly-expressed as just `@"\\\""`, but the problem is probably just as Maarten suggests below: typographic quotes.

Answer (score 4):

iOS 11 has added "Smart Punctuation" to the keyboard settings (see screenshot).

This means when typing "Course" it will convert it to “Course”. The '"' are replaced by a '“' and '”' string. These are different quotes (smart quotes) compared to the default ones.

So one option might be to also replace '“' and '”' by '\"'.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

@KishanLal Try this...

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"Course\""];
    NSLog(@"str = %@", str); //str = "Course"
    NSString *modifedSearchString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\""\""];
    NSLog(@"output = %@", modifedSearchString); //output = \"Course\"
```

Comment: I am getting the double quote string from search input. Can't hardcode doube code string. Backslash is virtual escape character, should be considered when input from search bar. Same code is working till iOS 10.